# DOL Wage and Hour data: Counting backwages under Fair Labor Standards Act

Tags: data.gov, government, csv, analysis, labor

I have a question about the Wage and Hour Compliance Action Data of the Department of Labor's Wage and Hour division:

```
http://prd-enforce-xfr-02.dol.gov/data_catalog/WHD/whd_whisard_20141105.csv.zip
```

Does anyone know what specifically is covered in the `flsa_bw_atp_amt` field of the database and how it's different from the fields, `flsa_mw_bw_atp_amt` and `flsa_ot_bw_atp_amt`? 
I know it means backwages agreed to pay under Fair Labor Standards Act, but I'm wondering how it differs from the other fields that also cover backwages under the same act. The data dictionary is not specific.

If I want to add up all the backwages collected under the Fair Labor Standards Act, what fields should I add up?

Answer (score 2):

There's a data catalog here: http://ogesdw.dol.gov/views/data_catalogs.php (and go to the Wage and Hour Compliance Action Data page). According to the dictionary, `flsa_bw_atp_amt` is the "BW Agreed to under FLSA (Fair Labor Standards Act)".

But it sounds like your question is more about how to get real qualitative information about the data fields. If that is the case I would suggest you try to speak with someone from the department. The WHD's website provides [contact information](http://www.dol.gov/whd/whdkeyp.htm) for several offices - I'd give them a call. I've found talking to a real live person to be infinitely helpful in figuring out what exactly I'm looking at.

Comment: Yes, thanks. In general that's a great idea. It's been nearly impossible to speak with a real person at the department. Their support for their data is abysmal.

Comment: Oof, I've had that experience. My sympathies.